# Fields of prime characteristic in which an irreducible polynomial has a root of multiplicity > 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, positive-characteristic

[image]

In the following solution to ex21 (iii) I do not understand the second last line. Is there a mistake?

The first summation implies the degree of $f$ is $n$ whereas the second summation implies the degree of $f$ is $np$?

Comment: This is only a bad notation. The second sum goes over multiples of $p$ which are less or equal to $n$. So you can replace $n$ by $\lfloor n/p\rfloor$.

Comment: That’s what I was thinking myself.